# How to et Knockout JS update the UI by changing Model property

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout, I assume it should allow to change the UI automatically by changing JS model property 
Please have a look a this code on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jt6bbeq4/2/

and tell me what am I missing? The update link should update the property name and so, auto update the Span Text from "Bob" to "Tedd"

**HTML:**

```
<a href='#' data-bind="click: update">Update Name</a><br/>
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
var viewModel = function () {
          var self = this;
          self.name = ko.observable('Bob');
          self.update = function () {

              this.name = 'Tedd';
          }
      };

var vm = new viewModel(); 
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: you forgot to include any jsfiddle link as well as the code in your question.

Comment: sorry I am new to stackoverflow too )
it is added now thanks

Comment: No worries, welcome aboard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the observable, not replace it:

```
this.name = 'Tedd'; // <-- observable replaced by string
this.name('Tedd');  // <-- value of observable replaced by new value
```

So it should be:

```
self.update = function () {
    self.name('Tedd');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jt6bbeq4/3/